# Como fazer uma consulta no sql-server para buscar informaçoes de data,sendo que o campo está definindo com data e hora

Tags: sql-server

O formato está definido da seguinte forma : '2022-09-05 15:14:25.747'. Gostaria de fazer buscas por ano, mes, dia ou utilizando horas.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Da pra fazer da seguinte forma:

*Por ano*

```
SELECT *
FROM suaTabela
WHERE YEAR(suaColunaDataHora) = 2022; -- Ou YEAR(GETDATE()) que pegaria o ano atual
```

*Por mês*

```
SELECT *
FROM suaTabela
WHERE YEAR(suaColunaDataHora) = 2022
  AND MONTH(suaColunaDataHora) = 9; -- Ou MONTH(GETDATE()) que pegaria o mês atual
```

*Por dia*

```
SELECT *
FROM suaTabela
WHERE YEAR(suaColunaDataHora) = 2022
  AND MONTH(suaColunaDataHora) = 9
  AND DAY(suaColunaDataHora) = 5; -- Ou DAY(GETDATE()) que pegaria o dia atual
```

*Por hora*

```
SELECT *
FROM suaTabela
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, suaColunaDataHora) = 15; -- Ou DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) que pegaria a hora atual
```

*Intervalo de datas*

```
SELECT *
FROM suaTabela
WHERE suaColunaDataHora >= '2022-09-05 00:00:00.000' -- Ou GETDATE() para o dia atual
  AND suaColunaDataHora < '2022-09-06 00:00:00.000'; -- Ou DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()) para somar 1 dia ao dia atual
```

Caso tenha uma váriavel que seja uma data você podera substituir pelo GETDATE().

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Dúvida respondida. Ajudou muito